# Find the expected value

Tags: probability

f the first roll in a game of craps is neither a natural nor craps, the player
can make an additional bet, equal to his original one, that he will make his
point before a seven turns up. If his point is four or ten he is paid off at 2 : 1
odds; if it is a five or nine he is paid off at odds 3 : 2; and if it is a six or eight
he is paid off at odds 6 : 5. Find the player’s expected winnings if he makes
this additional bet when he has the opportunity.

For this one, I thought there would be 36 total possibilities. So, I thought for 4 or 10, the chance is 
4/36. Also, for 5 or 9, we would get 3/36, and for 6 or 8, we would get 6/36. Then after using the epexted 
value formula, I kept getting the wrong answer. How should we find the correct expected value?

Comment: Is a craps a dice? What do you mean by paying into 2:1 odds? Can please you rephrase your question to make it more clear

Comment: What happens if the first roll is 3?

Comment: Summarising the rules for those unfamiliar with the game might help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y =$ The result of the first roll.

$P(Y \in \{7,11\}) = \frac {8}{36}\\
P(Y \in\{2,3,12\}) = \frac {4}{36}\\
P(Y \in\{4,5,6,8,9,10\}) = \frac {24}{36}$

That takes care of the come out.

For the subsequent rolls
Let $X$ be the result of the last roll
That $X$ is being rolled is conditional on the probability that the game isn't over yet.

$P(X = Y) = \frac {3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 5^2 + 4^2 + 3^2}{36\cdot24} = \frac {100}{864}$

$P(X = 7) = \frac {6}{36}$

Probability of the game ending on that roll.

$P(X =Y or X= 7) = \frac {244}{864}$

the probability that that you win assuming the game does not end on the come-out roll.

$\frac {P(X=Y)}{P(X\in\{Y,7\})} = \frac {100}{244}$

$P(Win, all scenarios) = \frac {8}{36} + \frac {24}{36}\frac {100}{244}$

$P(Lose, all scenarios) = \frac {4}{36} + \frac {24}{36}\frac {144}{244}$

If $W_1$ is the money staked on the pass line. $E[X] = W_1(P(win) - P(loss))$

What about the additional wagers?

If you choose to "back up" your bet and wager addition money, call it $W_2$ as it turns out $E[W_2] = 0$

Lets pick a one example 
$Y = 4.$  The odds that are offered to you are 2:1

$\frac {P(X=4)}{P(X=\{4,7\})}=\frac {3}{9}\\
\frac {P(X=7)}{P(X=\{4,7\})} = \frac {6}{9}\\
E[W_2] = W_2(2\cdot\frac {3}{9} - 1\cdot \frac 69) = 0$

And this is the case for all 6 of your potential points.

Since this is the about the only wager in the casino that does not actually favor the house, many gamblers will insist that you should always back up your craps wager to the maximum that the house will allow.

Comment: Tha nk u for your help!